# BarChart is not showing provided data

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am making an app which will show some statistics. I choose to make a Barchart with help of MPAndroidChart library. I have data from database. I will provide all inputs below

I was trying to follow this [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naPRHNfzDk8) with my values, but it seems that there is a problem somewhere.

**Main Activity**

```
        var popUpMenu: PopupMenu = PopupMenu(this, imageButton)

        popUpMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.array, popUpMenu.menu)
        popUpMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            textViewStatName.setText(it.title.toString())
            textViewStatNameLabel.setText(it.title.toString())
            val itemId= it.itemId
            if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_1) {

            }
            else if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_2) {
                val request: String = dbMethods.getStatistics(2)
                val barChart: BarChart = findViewById(R.id.barChart)
                var arrayList: ArrayList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()
                var typedArrayList = request.split(",").toTypedArray()
                typedArrayList = typedArrayList.dropLast(1).toTypedArray()
                var items = arrayOf<Array<String>>()
                var xAxisValues = ArrayList<String>()

                for (i in 0 until typedArrayList.size)
                {
                    items  += typedArrayList[i].split("-").toTypedArray()
                    arrayList.add(BarEntry(i.toFloat(), items[i][1].toFloat()))
                    xAxisValues.add(items[i][0])
                }

                var bds: BarDataSet = BarDataSet(arrayList, "First attempt")
                bds.setColor(Color.RED)
                //var ibds: ArrayList<IBarDataSet> = ArrayList()
                //ibds.add(bds)

                var barData: BarData = BarData(bds) //ibds
                barChart.data = barData
                barChart.xAxis.textColor = Color.WHITE
                barChart.axisLeft.textColor = Color.WHITE
                barChart.axisRight.textColor = Color.WHITE
                barChart.legend.textColor = Color.WHITE
                barChart.data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                barChart.description.text = "Description"
                barChart.isEnabled = true
            }
            else if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_3)
            {

            }
            else if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_4)
            {

            }
            true
        }
        popUpMenu.show()
```

**XML**

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/barChart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/statFromSpinner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/názovStatistikyLABEL"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/názovStatistikyLABEL"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
```

Basicly it works like this:

- I click on the item in popup menu
- Barchart should query a DB
- Data should be displayed

**arrayList** has three rows **{[0,8],[1,15],[2,16]}**

Non of the values seems to be null after debugging, but the chart has message **No chart data available**

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was that I needed to click on the BarChart to get a the values. If you encounter this problem just add these lines into your code

```
 barChart.invalidate()
 barChart.refreshDrawableState()
```

Hope this helps someone